# CryptoJS returned different values

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I'm new to using CryptoJS and I'm wondering why it is returning a different value after decrypting. The initial value is `hello world` but it doesn't return `hello world` after decrypting and I don't know why.

Code:

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
let text = 'hello world';
let Crypto = CryptoJS.Crypto;

function aesEncrypt(data) {
  let key = '6fa979f20126cb08aa645a8f495f6d85'; //length 32
  let iv = 'I8zyA4lVhMCaJ5Kg';
  let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
  });

  return cipher.toString();
}

function aesDecrypt(data) {
  let key = '6fa979f20126cb08aa645a8f495f6d85'; //length 32
  let iv = 'I8zyA4lVhMCaJ5Kg';
  let decipher = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
  });

  return decipher.toString();
}

console.log(aesEncrypt(text));
console.log(aesDecrypt(aesEncrypt(text)));
```

The encrypted value is 'J2T1uHeSNsgSgeBgziXU8w==' but the decrypted value is '68656c6c6f20776f726c64'.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
decipher.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

That's all